# RestController method not getting invoked

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have created a spring boot application to work spring batch framework.But unfornunately none of the RestController method is working:

My RestController class is as below

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/myapp")
public class MyBatchController {
  @Autowired
  private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("myJob")
  private Job myJob;

   @PostMapping(value = "/invokeMyJob")
   @CrossOrigin
   public ResponseEntity<String> processStock(){
    JobExecution myJobExecution = null;
    ResponseEntity<String> myJobResponse = null;
    JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
            .toJobParameters();
    try {
        myJobExecution = jobLauncher.run(myJob, jobParameters);
        myJobResponse = new ResponseEntity<String>(myJobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode(), HttpStatus.OK); 
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        myJobResponse = new ResponseEntity<String>("failure", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); 
      }
    return myJobResponse;
    }
 }
```

PFB my postman response

[image]

My Main application class is as below:

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = "{com.myapp.batch}")
 public class MybatchApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(MybatchApplication.class, args);
   }
 }
```

I am not able to track why I am getting 404 in postman???

Comment: `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.myapp.batch"})`

Comment: Don't need to use `@ComponentScan` if everything is in the root package.